# Enum.ToString Not Working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, enums

Check This Code Sniplet out.

```
using (AttendanceDataContext db = new AttendanceDataContext())
{
var attendance = db.attendpunches.Select(at => new RawEmployeeCheckInOutInfo
                    {
                        CheckTime = at.punchtime.Value,
                        Direction = ((AttendanceDirection)at.direction.Value).ToString()
                    });
```

...

AttendanceDirection is enum Which is...

```
public enum AttendanceDirection : int
{
    CheckIn = 1,
    CheckOut = 2
}
```

The Problem is The Direction = ((AttendanceDirection)at.direction.Value).ToString() is always returning the byte value.

Comment: What kind of column type do you have in the DB? And what type is `at.direction.Value`?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `.Value` part in that line?

Comment: The Data Type of direction is int and the same thing happens when i remove the .value, Any way "Jon Skeet" solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the `ToString` is being effectively performed at the database side, which doesn't know the enum names. Try this:

```
var attendance = db.attendpunches
                   .Select(at => new { CheckTime = at.punchtime.Value, 
                                       Direction = at.direction.Value })
                   .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the query in-process...
                   .Select(at => new RawEmployeeCheckInOutInfo {
                       CheckTime = at.CheckTime,
                       Direction = ((AttendanceDirection) at.Direction).ToString()
                    });
```